# Designing a typical GUI for editing entities [desktop application]

Tags: user-interface, desktop, usability, entities

I have little experience in developing GUI for desktop applications, but I want to develop a typical GUI for creating/editing entities (e.g. Customer, Suppliers, etc.) which would be similar for many cases and would be comfortable for the users.

[* Please don't close the question. I put much effort in preparing the question and I really need help. *]

After analyzing our tasks I designed the following possible options:

1) In simple cases it is possible to solve the task by using an ordinary grid:

[image: grid only]

I.e. the workflow is: On pressing the Add button, a new row is added to the grid. On pressing Delete the user is asked for confirmation if he/she really wants to delete the focused entity instance. On pressing Save all previously made changes are saved. On pressing Close the form is closed (user is asked if he/she wants to save changes before closing).

Cons: I think such a GUI will only work for very simple cases. Editing something complex in a grid is not comfortable neither for a user nor for a developer (implementing complex editing in a grid will not be trivial I think).

2) For more complex entities the following option is possible:

[image: grid and modal form for creating/editing]

The grid is used here only in the read only mode. On pressing Add a modal form for filling information about a new entity is shown. On pressing OK in that form the data is validated and if everything is ok the object is added to the grid datasource. On double clicking on a grid row the same form for editing the chosen entity instance is shown.

Cons: For every entity we will have to create 2 forms.

3) Another possible option:

[image: grid will fields on the same form]

The grid is also in the read only mode. When focusing a row in the grid, the fields above the grid are filled and a user can edit them. On pressing Add a new entity instance (object) is created and added to the grid's datasource, then the new row is focused, fields above the grid are cleared (binding helps here), the cursor is placed to the first field and the user can start typing.

I don't see any cons here except that maybe you will not have enough place for the grid and the fields on the same form. I like this option though I don't remember that I saw it anywhere.

---

I tried to ask the users of my program to help me decide which GUI is better for  them, but the typical answers are "I think both options are ok" or "I don't know, you decide which one is better".

Now I would like to ask people with experience in GUI design the following questions:

1) Which option do you use usually? Maybe another one (not shown above)?
2) Would be nice if you also said a couple of words about your implementation   (dataset/custom business objects/binding, etc.)
3) Which cons did you notice in my options?
4) Any advice on what I can read on the subject?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Please don't close the question. I put much effort in preparing the question and I really need help.

Comment: Sorry Junior1993. This question is not good for the Q&A format. You should reference this nice write up in chats or a forum somewhere.

Comment: Peter, the problem is I already posted that question on another big forum 2 days ago, but got only 1 answer (the guy said option #2 is better). That is why I decided to try Stackoverflow. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Junior1993, This is a great question, and there are many online resources that will spell out the trade-offs of each of these interaction design patterns, when to use them, and when they are most effective. You did not provide project-specific details, so it's impossible to answer those questions.

The "Work With" pattern is the foundation of your write-up, and you were asking about the pros and cons of different variations. Here is some reading on "Work With": http://quince.infragistics.com/html/PatternView.aspx?name=Work+With

All of the patterns you described are well-documented and can be modified to fit different purposes.
Your #2 pattern is "Edit-In-Place". It can also be found on the Quince site. 
Your #3 pattern is "Two-panel selector". 
This one takes many forms, but it helps to preserve context while editing.

The one you did not mention was "New-Item Row". You might want to look at that one, too, and select the pattern or combination of patterns that best fits your users' goals and the content they are creating/editing.

There are other pattern websites out there, and most build on the work of Jennifer Tidwell, author of "Designing Interfaces", an interaction design classic.

Best of luck to you!